# Ubuntu 16 fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory (Unsolved with python-devel)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, pycaffe

When trying to compile pycaffe on Ubuntu 16.04, with Anaconda 3.6 installed I get the following error:

```
python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:1:52: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to install the python-devel packages with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

But even after trying with each of those separately the same error occurs.

The correct PATH seems to be added in .bashrc

```
export PATH="home/jdevezas/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

And in Caffe's makefile.config I have

```
# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
#PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.

ANACONDA_HOME := /home/jdevezas/anaconda

#PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
#            $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
#            $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
 PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
 PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

I have also tried with Python 2.7 with no results. Suggestions?

Comment: My solution was to manually add to the include path /usr/include/python3.5

Answer (score 1):

First check which version of Python is installed. Let's say version 3.11. After cloning the repo, go to 'build.sh' file and edit the gcc line to your Python version i.e. 3.8 to 3.11.

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.8 -o torghost torghost.c -lpython3.8 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

***TO***

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.11 -o torghost torghost.c -lpython3.11 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

Now it will build and compile.

Answer (score 0):

For python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For python 3+:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Afterwards, try doing:

```
locate Python.h
```

And use the directory it finds in your makefile. It appears that the header file is in */usr/include/python2.7/*

Comment: perhaps after installing the above he should try `locate Python.h` to see where it actually is located. On my ubuntu workstation it's in `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`